# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in

Tags: php, bindparam

I am getting a error while running below code any one here pls help me out

```
public function storeUser($name, $email, $password, $phone,$stream) {

   $response = array();

    $uuid = uniqid('', true);
    $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
    $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
    $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt

    if (!$this->isUserExisted($email)) {

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, phone,stream, salt, created_at) VALUES('$uuid','$name','$email',$'$encrypted_password','$phone','$stream','$salt',NOW())");
        $stmt->bind_param("isssisss", $uuid,$name,$email,$encrypted_password,$phone,$stream,$salt,NOW());

        $result = $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->close();

        if ($result) {

            // User successfully inserted
            $response["error"] = false;
            $response["user"] = $this->getUserByEmailAndPassword($email);
        }else {

            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred while registereing";
        }


    } else {

        $response["error"] = false;
        $response["user"] = $this->getUserByEmailAndPassword($email);
    }

      return $response;

}
```

the error is

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in
>   /var/www/html/android_login_api_test/include/DB_Functions.php on line
>   98

Comment: It means your SQL query failed / is invalid.  Try running it through PHPMyAdmin to see what happened.  Also, your VALUES should be question marks if those are what you are binding values to through bind_param.

Comment: Replace the variable name in the query to `?` and remove `NOW()` from the parameters in `bind_param`

Comment: I take it you didn't bother reading and understanding exactly "how" prepared statements work http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're preparing a query without placeholders, i.e.:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, phone,stream, salt, created_at) VALUES('$uuid','$name','$email',$'$encrypted_password','$phone','$stream','$salt',NOW())");
$stmt->bind_param("isssisss", $uuid,$name,$email,$encrypted_password,$phone,$stream,$salt,NOW());
```

It seems to me you copy-pasted the code. Replace the code above with:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, phone,stream, salt, created_at) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,NOW())");
$stmt->bind_param("isssiss", $uuid,$name,$email,$encrypted_password,$phone,$stream,$salt);
```

Note I dropped the last parameter in the `bind_param` function, and the last 's' in the first argument of said function.

Comment: thank you so much it works for  me

Answer (score -2):

`$stmt` stores result of `prepare` function. Seems like `prepare` doesn't return object, but you trying to access `$stmt` as an object.